# Optical Flow vs. Haar Cascade

Tags: ipad, opencv

intend to programme navigating an iPad App with head motions (originally hand motions, but hands seem to difficult to detect at the moment): left, right, up and down. So I plan to use openCV and either detect the optical flow of the head area, or detect the ears and head of the user with haar cascades (openCV is delivered with quite precise head and ear xmls). Can anyone offer some advice on which solution to use? Will one of the mentioned need more power? Ear and head detection might be easier to programme? I would like to avoid to much effort in the wrong direction and don't have much expertise in my current surroundings...

thank you for any help, advice, ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Haar cascades because optical flow is more expensive in computing time!

Comment: Thank you, then cascading it is!

Answer (score 0):

Is using the native face detection in iOS 5 not an option for what you want?
I'm thinking outside the box here, but I've been with OpenCV before and it still hurts..

http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/

*The idea of course, being that you apply this to live input somehow

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointer! Will definitely try out the classes - couldn't find much information on the new classes, so I will have to check on detecting the profile. One cannot detect ears, but eyes. So obviously, if the left eye is missing, the user has either blinked (hope its not that accurate) or turned his head to the left (this is what I need). But definitely a good tip, since this detection is quickly implemented... will keep you posted!

Comment: Hi, tried it out. The native face detection is too good? CIDetection detects face, eyes and mouth. So the theory was, if it can't detect the left eye, but the face, the user must have turned his face to the left. Sadly, hasEyePosition always returns true and holds a position, even if I turn so my nose and forehead are covering the eye. If I hide the eye successfully, the whole face is no longer detected. This is definitely the future way of handling matters, but at the moment there aren't enough features and information to access. Thank you for your thoughts, though!

Comment: alright worth the try and we all learned something :-D Good luck with finding the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using Hidden Markov Models. There is a lot of research material(working prototypes) on how to use HMMs to recognize head gestures.

I believe ear haar classifiers are not that effective with cluttered background. Please let us know if you've got it to work!

Comment: Hi, I can tell you now: No, its pretty awful. OpenCV actually comes with haar classifiers for left and right ear - based on about 5000 images. But my ears (average ears, I hope) are seldom recognized as such, seems random and not improvable with different light settings etc. The ear has to be held into the camera for quite some time until it is detected. I have enquired how to improve accuracy and reaction time and am currently waiting. Will look into Hidden Markov Models immediately. It is this and "not really Jakes" answer, which I will check next and post the results! Thank you for this!

Comment: I thought so. Execept for face and eye (to some extent) classifier, all others do not work efficiently. HMMs have experimental implementation in OpenCV (cvaux.h). But I don't think it is being developed into a full fledged API. I can say to have an effective implmentation in OpenCV, do face/nose detection(use centroid point)and do Kalman Tracking. This way you can even detect direction in x<--->y plane.